# How do I know if a return value is an array or scalar in Hibernate .list() method?

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate

I am using the following very basic code. I am using Hibernate to run native SQL queries against a read-only Oracle database for an internal app. I am allowing the users to define queries for later running.

Most queries will return rowsets, meaning many columns and possibly many rows.

But, lets say somebody uses "Select sysdate from DUAL" to test something... This will return an Object[] with a single item of type Timestamp, so the code below will blow up because it can't cast Timestamp to Object[]

How do I, with reflection or something, tell what's in that outer array so as to know how to handle it? If it's just an object and not an array, I just want to toString() it. If it's an array, I want to toString the 1st column of every row into a single string. Weird I know, but I really learning here too.

```
List<Object[]> rows = sqlQuery.list();

String result = "";
if (rows.isEmpty())
return "NORESULTS";
else
{
    for(Object[] row : rows){
        result+=row[0].toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `obj.getClass().isArray()` to check if the object is an array and use `Array.get(obj, index)` to retrieve the first index. But make sure you handle the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in case the array is empty.

```
private static String asString(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return "null";

    Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
    if (clazz.isArray()) {
        try {
            Object first = Array.get(obj, 0);
            return String.valueOf(first);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return "empty array";
        }
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(obj); // primitive or non-array object
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(4);
    String[] stringArray = new String[] { "a", "b" };
    String nothing = null;
    int primitive = 4;
    char[] primitiveArray = { 'a', 'b' };
    int[] emptyArray = new int[0];

    System.err.println(asString(integer));        // 4
    System.err.println(asString(stringArray));    // a
    System.err.println(asString(nothing));        // null
    System.err.println(asString(primitive));      // 4
    System.err.println(asString(primitiveArray)); // a
    System.err.println(asString(emptyArray));     // empty array
}
```

I hope this is what you asked for.

**EDIT**

and this for the result list:

```
private static List<String> rowsAsString(List<?> rows) {
    if (rows == null || rows.isEmpty())
        return Collections.emptyList();

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(rows.size());
    for (Object row : rows) {
        strings.add(asString(row));
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: Yes! This hit the nail on the head! Thanks for the quick response!